# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: when MapsActivity with marker refreshed infinitely

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have a MapsActivity with 5-6 marker on it. My client requires to refresh the activity every 2 minutes. After several times refreshed, the OutOfMemoryError occurs. Checking the Android Profiler, I noticed every time the activity refreshed, the old instance of the activity is being destroyed by the garbage collector.

This is the code...

```
 //for draw child user location dynamically
    private void drawDynamicMap(double latitude, double longitude, final String title,
                                final String groupDatetime, String status, String type, GoogleMap googleMap) {
        if (latitude == 0.0 && longitude == 0.0) {
//            return;
        }
        mMap = googleMap;
        final LatLng cordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        //for setting image marker
        View marker = getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_layout, null);
        View carMarker = getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_car_marker_layout, null);
        // Dashboard Button Work
        ImageView markerImage = (ImageView) marker.findViewById(R.id.marker_image);
        /*NavigationActionbar.*/
        if (!image.equals("")) {
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(image) /// if load from JSON .load(responseJSON.getString("image"))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.noimage)
                    .error(R.drawable.noimage)
                    .resize(80, 80)
                    .into(markerImage);
        }
        if (mMap == null) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            refreshMapActivity();
        }
        childMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(cordinate)
                .title(title)
                .snippet(status + ", On - " + groupDatetime));
        if (type.equals("APP")) {
            childMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(marker)));
        } else {
            childMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(carMarker)));
        }
        childMarkers.add(childMarker);
    }
```

This is the Error in logcat...

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4194316 byte allocation with 1081744 free bytes and 1056KB until OOM
                                                      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                      at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
                                                      at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:812)
                                                      at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:789)
                                                      at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:756)
                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.k.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951248:7)
                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.ah.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951248:73)
                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.ah.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951248:46)
                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.ah.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951248:39)
                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.ae.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951248:59)
                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.am.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951248:346)
                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.cb.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951248:407)
                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951248:664)
                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951248:270)
                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bb.f(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951248:257)
                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bb.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951248:11)
```

Note: sometimes my device is hanging and also forcefully restarted. Currently I am working with memory leaks and I have successfully eliminate some of the leaks with context and inner classes.

I am suspecting that the error is related to Bitmap, that is why I put the above code. If any other details needed, ping me.

But I have no clue, how to solve this problem. I hope, if anyone faced same kind of problem in the past.

Comment: "My client requires to refresh the activity every 2 minutes" -- what **exactly** does "refresh the activity" mean? "every time the activity refreshed, the old instance of the activity is being destroyed by the garbage collector" -- why is there an "old instance of the activity"?

Comment: When you refresh activity you shouldn't create whole activity again. Just fetch the data you need and change necessary things. For example if you need to change the marker position according to the data. You should fetch and change just the markers's position.

Comment: "Just fetch the data you need and change necessary things." - I know this policy, but unfortunately the activity already has too many complexities in it, thus implementing it is not feasible at all. My question is that if the activity destroyed totally, why is there OutOfMemoryError after 5-6 times refresh?